# Reshaping a SAS Table not using IML

Tags: arrays, dataframe, sas, transpose, sas-iml

I am wondering if it is possible to reshape the following `have` table in SAS not using SAS/IML to produce the `want` table.

**Have:**

```
+--------+------+------+------+
|  NAME  | var1 | var2 | var3 |
+--------+------+------+------+
| Q1_ID1 |    1 |    2 |    3 |
| Q1_ID2 |    4 |    5 |    6 |
| Q2_ID1 |    7 |    8 |    9 |
| Q2_ID2 |   10 |   11 |   12 |
| Q3_ID1 |   13 |   14 |   15 |
| Q3_ID2 |   16 |   17 |   18 |
+--------+------+------+------+
```

**Want:**

```
+----------+----+----+----+
|   NAME   | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
+----------+----+----+----+
| var1_ID1 |  1 |  7 | 13 |
| var1_ID2 |  4 | 10 | 16 |
| var2_ID1 |  2 |  8 | 14 |
| var2_ID2 |  5 | 11 | 17 |
| var3_ID1 |  3 |  3 | 15 |
| var3_ID2 |  6 |  6 | 18 |
+----------+----+----+----+
```

The code to reproduce the `have` table is the following:

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=",";
input NAME :$8. var1 :8. var2 :8. var3 :8.;
datalines;
Q1_ID1,1,2,3
Q1_ID2,4,5,6
Q2_ID1,7,8,9
Q2_ID2,10,11,12
Q3_ID1,13,14,15
Q3_ID2,16,17,18
;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two transposes are needed, with some tearing apart and putting together in between.

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter=",";
input NAME :$8. var1 :8. var2 :8. var3 :8.;
datalines;
Q1_ID1,1,2,3
Q1_ID2,4,5,6
Q2_ID1,7,8,9
Q2_ID2,10,11,12
Q3_ID1,13,14,15
Q3_ID2,16,17,18
;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=stage;
  by name;
  var var:;
run;

data stage2(keep=name col1 qtr);
  set stage;
  qtr = scan(name,1,'_');           * tear apart;
  id = scan(name,2,'_');
  name = catx('_', _name_, id);     * put together;
run;

proc sort data=stage2;
  by name qtr;
run;

proc transpose data=stage2 out=want;
  by name;
  id qtr;
run;
```